# Why do the PointerAlignment options not work?

Tags: c++, formatting, clang, clang-format

I'm using clang-format (`version 8.0.0 (tags/google/stable/2019-01-18)`) with a style file, in which I set

```
…
PointerAlignment: Left
…
```

This succeeds in transforming declarations such as this one

```
const string &foo = "lorem ipsum";
```

into

```
const string& foo = "lorem ipsum";
```

However, when I also include in my style file

```
BasedOnStyle: Google
```

the options do not do anything. For some reason, they get overridden by the base style. This seems nonsensical to me – the explicit options should override the base style instead, no?
Can somebody explain what the problem is and how to use both `BasedOnStyle` and `PointerAlignment: Left`?

Comment: `PointerBindsToType` is legacy (is not anymore there in the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), you have to go back to previous versions to see it, for example [3.4](https://releases.llvm.org/3.4/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)), just use `PointerAlignment` (either `Left`, `Right` or `Middle`).

Comment: Why did you edit the question? It was valid for the version explicitly mentioned up top.

Comment: It would be valid also for current version, `PointerBindsToType` is still a supported option but it is a legacy option. If you use at the same time `PointerAlignment` and `PointerBindsToType` the first one will make the second irrelevant. In the version you mention (8), `PointerBindsToType` was already made legacy (and therefore not mentioned in the documentation): https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.1/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

This question has more value if it shows cleaner usage of clang-format.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is that the Google style (one can inspect it with `clang-format -style=google -dump-config | less`) defines

```
DerivePointerAlignment: true
```

The documentation says it

> If true, analyze the formatted file for the most common alignment of & and *. Pointer and reference alignment styles are going to be updated according to the preferences found in the file. **PointerAlignment is then used only as fallback**.

Which means one must explicitly set `DerivePointerAlignment: false` if one wants to handle it by oneself.